# Optimized Parameters of `FFMPEG` for Screen Recording

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, compression, screen-casting

Windows has a great codec for screen recording called [Windows Media Video Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Video#Windows_Media_Video_Screen).
It generates artifacts free videos which are highly compressed (small size).

I was wondering, what would be the equivalent using `FFMPEG`?
Are there parameters to be set for any codec in `FFMPEG` which can yield similar results?
Is there a mode for lossless intra and inter compression?

If not, what would be a good set of parameters for `FFMPEG` for this task?